# Digg Compact Button

Tags: digg

Does anyone also have problems with the digg social bookmark button? I'm using the compact one. It does not display the label and the digg count. It only displays the icon which is not what I'm going for. Has anyone encountered this as well? I've used different codes from different sites but it's still displaying the same thing

Comment: Can you add an example of the problem?

Answer (score -1):

They are doing a major relaunch over the coming weeks. However, the API doesn't seem to work at the moment.